CurrentPageReference executing too early when open second component tab in Workspace Api
We have a component on a PersonAccount page in Service Cloud that shows a list of records.  In each row there is a 'View' button to open additional information about the record.  The additional information is an LWC component that is dependent on the state parameters that are being passed via the page reference.  The first opening of the sub tab works as expected.  But if I go back to the original list and click View on a different record, the second tab opens, but does not have any data from the page reference.
The code that opens the sub tab:
    async showClaimInformation(event){
        var recordIndex = event.target.dataset.value;
        const docRecord = this.records[recordIndex];

        if (!this.isConsoleNavigation || !this.enclosingTabId) {
            return;
        }

        let tabInfo = await getTabInfo(this.enclosingTabId);
        let parentTabId = tabInfo.isSubtab ? tabInfo.parentTabId : tabInfo.tabId;

        await openSubtab(
            parentTabId, {
            pageReference : {
                type : 'standard__component',
                attributes : {
                    componentName : 'c__childComponentDetails',
                    actionName: 'view'
                },
                state : {
                    c__cNumber : docRecord.requestNumber,
                    c__cExtId : docRecord.externalId,
                    uid : recordIndex
                }
            },
            focus : true,
            label : docRecord.requestNumber + ' Details',
            icon : 'standard:medication_dispense'
        });
          
    }

The Child Component Metatada
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>61.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__UrlAddressable</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>

Child Component Javascript File
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class ChildComponentDetails extends LightningElement {
    @wire(CurrentPageReference)
    getStateParameters(currentPageReference) {
        if (currentPageReference) {
            this.cId= currentPageReference.state?.c__cNumber;
            this.absId= currentPageReference.state?.c__cExtId;
            this.cardTitle = 'Additional Details for ' + this.cId;
        }
     }

    cardTitle;
    cId;
    absExtId;
}

After adding MANY debuggers and running through the code, the behavior I observed was that the first open of the component, the Page Reference executes and has the state values as expected.
Leaving that tab open and clicking View on a Second record, the CurrentPageReference method runs, but in the context of the parent record prior to completing the openSubTab async method.  This means that cId and asbId are undefined, furthermore, this executes PRIOR to the component actually being loaded.  It will have a 'Loading...' tab with zero details.
Once the URL DOES update the CurrentPageReference method does not run again with the updated values.  This final code does not have my many different approaches.
I tried renderedCallback, but it did not run again after the page reference was updated with the correct state.
I tried a setter on CurrentPageReference but it never fired, even when it was set initially.
I had also considered changing the state of the child component in a connected callback, but I didn't go that route, because even if I trigger the component to rerender its state there, it still isn't referencing the correct pageReference to update.
Also note, that if you refresh the individual tab, the state is captured correctly and the sub tab loads as you would expect.
In aura, you'd just use a change event on the page reference, but again, since the setter didn't run, I would assume a change event is also not being captured, as it seems to be running in the context of the parent, instead of the component that is being opened with the state parameters.
Is there some other way to capture the changes on the CurrentPageReference in LWC?
I did come up with a workaround for this, however, I would like to know if I'm missing anything with the original intention of how using current page reference should be running when you open multiple sub tabs.
And for, inquiring minds that would like to know, this is my workaround. A .then promise is returned with the tabId and then call RefreshTab.
    await openSubtab(
        parentTabId, {
        pageReference : {
            type : 'standard__component',
            attributes : {
                componentName : 'c__childComponentDetails',
                actionName: 'view'
            },
            state : {
                c__cNumber : docRecord.requestNumber,
                c__cExtId : docRecord.externalId,
                uid : recordIndex
            }
        },
        focus : true,
        label : docRecord.requestNumber + ' Details',
        icon : 'standard:medication_dispense'
    });
   .then(sTabId => {
    refreshTab(sTabId, {includeAllSubtabs : false});
   });

